# Absolute positioning inside relative with 100% width

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to set width of absolute element 100% and fit the screen ( not parent ) inside relative element?
Here is my code

```
<div class="relative">

     ...

     <div class="absolute"></div>

     ...

</div>
```

Css code:

```
.relative{

position:relative;
width:600px;
}

.absolute{

border:1px solid red //draw a line across screen

position:absolute;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please share your html code as well.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig i add it

Comment: What do you mean by "fit the screen inside relative element"?

Comment: It already takes width:100%, what you want actually.

Comment: I want draw a line with browser width not parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use `100vw` which is equal to window width and also use `calc` to position of absolute element. So if width of parent element is `50%` to position absolute element to `left: 0` of window you can use `transform: translate(calc(-100vw + 75%))` which in this case is equal to `-25vw`.

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  height: 2px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translate(calc(-100vw + 75%), -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's happen if width=500px not percent?

Answer (score 3):

Just set left: 20px; and right: 20px; and remove width: 100%

```
.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid thin #06F;
}
```

or add left: 20px; and the calc function width: calc( 100% - 40px )

```
.box2 {
position: absolute;
width: calc( 100% - 40px );
padding: 50px 0;
color: #000;
background: #fff;
border: solid thin #06F;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a 1px height div for the line and give it 100vw width.

HTML

```
<div class="relative">

     ...

     <div class="absolute"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
     ...

</div>
```

CSS

```
.relative{
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
}
.line {
  height:1px;
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
}
.absolute{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3ysh1rwt/2/

Comment: oh same with my idea. up for you :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
.relative{
  position:relative;
}

.absolute{
width:100%;
height:1px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From one edge of the screen to the next edge is a full length of viewport. The easiest way to achieve that is using `vw` (viewport width) 100vw is full width of viewport. To stretch out the absolute positioned div left and right are both at 0. Made a line by using `border-bottom`.

```css
div {} .A {
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
  height: 200px;
}
.B {
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='A'>
  <div class='B'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@CooPer: If the parent with position relative doesn't have 100% width, the child with position absolute will fit the "parent" width if you set 100% width for child element. 
Meaning the child class will account for 300px of border only as below example.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;//draw a line across screen
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So if you want child 100% and fit the screen. Try below.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid red;//draw a line across screen
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;//take up 100% viewport width
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**vw, vh** was supported since IE9.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp